# What is the complexity of the below code with respect to memory?

Tags: string, memory, complexity-theory, big-o

I read about Big-O Notation from [here](http://www.cforcoding.com/2009/07/plain-english-explanation-of-big-o.html) and had few questions on calculating the complexity.So for the below code i have calculated the complexity. need your inputs for the same.

```
    private void reverse(String strToRevers) 
    {
        if(strToRevers.length() == 0)
        {
            return ;
        }
        else 
        {
            reverse(strToRevers.substring(1));
            System.out.print(strToRevers.charAt(0));
        }
    }
```

If the memory factor is considered then the complexity of above code for a string of n characters is O(n^2). The explanation is for a string that consists of n characters, the below function would be called recursively n-1 times and each function call creates a string of single character(stringToReverse.charAT(0)). Hence it is n*(n-1)*2 which translates to o(n^2). Let me know if this is right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Hence it is n*(n-1)*2 which translates to o(n^2). Let me know if this is right ?

Almost: it's `n * (n-1) / 2`, not `*2`, which is also O(n^2). Note that o(n^2) (little-O) **[means something else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Little-o_notation)**, so the distinction is important.

This is assuming we're considering this as pseudocode. Language-specific implementations and smart compilers may be able to improve the running time substantially. For instance, a compiler that can observe that you're simply reversing the string might just do an in-place reverse, which is O(n).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like Java, so it's *not* O(n**2). That's because strings share the underlying character sequence buffers; they can do this because they are immutable objects.

But it is O(n) in stack space. That's not good. It's better to allocate a mutable working buffer of characters, reverse the string into that, and then print the whole lot at once.

Comment: +1. The `System.out` and other small things point to it being Java, where `substring` does not duplicate the original `String` character array.  This is 1 reason there is a `String(String)` constructor.

Comment: For the sake of example, dont consider the fact that in java the substring shares the underlying character sequence. Assume that each time a memory is allocated for the new string.